# Python for-loop in range not providing desired result

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I have the following python for-loop which is supposed to loop round `RANGE` numbers of time. I specify `RANGE` at the start of the code, so for example, imagine the range is 5.

There is then a uuid_list containing 2 uuids. There should be a message created for each.

```
for i in range(RANGE):
                data = MESSAGE[i]
                message = data
                mqtt_connection.publish(topic=TOPIC, payload=json.dumps(message), 
                qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
                print("Published: '" + json.dumps(message) + "' to the topic: " + TOPIC)
                t.sleep(20)
```

Since I have specified the `RANGE` as 5, I am expecting a result of 5 generated messages for EACH uuid. However, with the above code, I am only getting 5 messages for the first uuid.

To try and rectify this I have also tried ...

```
for i in range(RANGE):
                data = MESSAGE[i+1]
                message = data
                mqtt_connection.publish(topic=TOPIC, payload=json.dumps(message), 
                qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
                print("Published: '" + json.dumps(message) + "' to the topic: " + TOPIC)
                t.sleep(20)
```

The `RANGE` is still 5. **But** now I am getting 8 messages for the first uuid and 2 for the second uuid.

Can anyone please advise how my line `data = MESSAGE[i]` should be specified in order to achieve the desired `RANGE` for each uuid?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is `MESSAGE`? What are its values? Where are you using `uuid_list`, I don't see it in the code you posted.

Comment: @Shiva I've included the entire code now for you to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `for i in range(RANGE)`, `i` value ranges from 0 to 4 and that will access only the first 5 elements of `MESSAGE`

For `RANGE = 5` and two uuids `MESSAGE` has 5 * 2 = 10 elements. To fetch all ten messages, you can either do

```
for i in range(RANGE * len(uuid_list):
    message = MESSAGE[i]
    # rest of the code
```

OR

```
for message in MESSAGE:
    # rest of the code
```